# What are the possible reasons why modal doesn't shows?

Tags: laravel

I have two button for modal and created two modal included in my blade file which I'm trying to use but it doesn't seem to work, I tried deleting the other button but doesn't seem to work, which I assumed to be the case

What could have been the reason for the modals not to show up?

this is my button modals

```
    <td class="table-danger"><button id="aaaBtn" class="soldbtn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#soldModal{{$data->id}}">SOLD</button></td>
    
    <td class="table-warning"><button id="bbbBtn" class="updatebtn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateModal{{$data->id}}" >UPDATE</button></td>

    <!-- Modal -->                   
    <div class="modal fade" id="updateModal{{$data->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateModalLabel{{$data->id}}" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
            <img src="assets/images/rice.png">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="contact-form">
            <form id="contact" action="{{url('/reservation')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12" align="center">
                <h3>{{$data->title}}</h3>
                <img height="200" width="200" src="productimage/{{$data->image}}">
                <h5 class='m-2'>~ KILOS ~</h5>
                </div>


        </div>
        <div class="row col-12">
        @foreach($modal_data as $modal_data)
        <div class="row sm-6 ml-4 mb-1" class="no-gutters" style="height:25px; width: auto;">
            <p class='text-dark mr-2'><input type="checkbox" name="prod_kilos[]" value="{{$modal_data->kg}}" id="checkitem" class="check-cls"/> {{$modal_data->kg}}kg </p>
            <p class='text-dark'>Qty:</p><input style="width:80px; height:25px;" type="number" name="prod_qty[{{$modal_data->kg}}]" min="1" value="1" max="{{$modal_data->warehouse_qty}}" class="form-control ml-2">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_name[{{$modal_data->kg}}]" value="{{$modal_data->title}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_fee[{{$modal_data->kg}}]" value="{{$modal_data->price}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="prod_id[{{$modal_data->kg}}]" value="{{$modal_data->id}}">
        </div>
        @endforeach 
        </div>
        <div class=" col-lg-12 mt-5">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="form-submit"  class="submit-btn" >ADD TO CART</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End Modal -->
```

Comment: So, how are we going to know when there's no code to look at? Please update your question with your code.

Comment: I've changed it, I don't know why, why it wasn't post even though I did

Comment: Check the answer provided out, and if you need to pass an id to the button, it should be `data-target="#updateModal{{$data->id}}"` provided if it's in loop

Comment: yes, it's also one of the things I've tried but still doesn't show the modal

Answer (score 0):

**What is the problem?**

I think the reason why it is not working is because you set wrong `data-target` to the button:

```
<button data-target="#updateModal">UPDATE</button>
```

But when creating modal you use:

```
<!-- Modal -->                   
<div id="updateModalModal{{$data->id}}">
</div>
<!-- End Modal -->
```

Your `data-target` attributes does not correspond with each other.

**How to solve?**

The `data-target` attribute should point to an existing element in page, changing it to:

```
<button data-target="#updateModal{{$data->id}}">UPDATE</button>

<!-- Modal -->                   
<div id="updateModal{{$data->id}}">
</div>
<!-- End Modal -->
```

should solve the problem.

Hope it helps. Read more about it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo).

Comment: oh yes, I actually also tried that but still didn't work, that's also another reason I posted. I'll just edit my code above

Comment: your code is still incorrect, you use the id `updateModalModal{{$data->id}}` for the modal and `#updateModal{{$data->id}}` for the button's target attribute.
Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: my bad, I didn't notice the duplicate, really having a headache trying to fix it, but I already removed it in my latest code and the result is the same

Comment: Did you connect the bootstrap js file? Do you have any error in console?